# how to make CI display failed status if fastlane failed

Tags: gitlab-ci, fastlane

I am writing a build script to work on `gitlab ci`.
Part of the script is written with the help of `fastlane`.
However, if fastlane fails, the ci still **declares the job as succeeded**.
What do I need to put in the script, so that if fastlane fails, the job will be declared failed?